# Change laravel homestead default web server

Tags: laravel, apache, nginx, homestead

I am developing different web applications on `Laravel Homestead Branch 20.04` development environment generaly I develop apps running on `nginx` web server but one time I needed to run legacy app on `Apache` so I put in `Homestead.yaml` site settings as below:

```
sites:
    - map: site.test
      to: /home/vagrant/site-project/
      type: "apache"
,
,
,
with other sites settings
```

Everything runs normally and I was running `flip` shell command to switch between servers, but after I delete the project and removed site settings from `Homestead.yaml` and run `vagrant reload --provision`. `Apache` web server always runs as default server and I need to run `flip` to switch to `nginx` web server even there is no site type is 'apache'.

The question is how can I return `nginx` server to be the default one?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should issue next commands in vagrant's (homestead's) terminal:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop && sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

Comment: no that didn't work after reloading the vagrant box I checked the status of the servers: nginx was off, and apache2 was on

Comment: I'm looking to change Homestead.yaml default site url... good chance that both these tasks would be completed in the same place?  
  
Just starting my search - `homestead make --help` shows only a few options available for changing, like the default IP.